# Create c# instance of generic type using <cfobject> in BlueDragon.NET's implementation of ColdFusion

Tags: c#, .net, generics, coldfusion, bluedragon

Using New Atlanta's BlueDragon.NET implementation of ColdFusion, we have the ability to create instances of C# .NET objects using the  cold fusion tag.  For example:

```
<cfobject name="list" type=".net" action="CREATE"
 class="System.Collections.ArrayList">
```

In one case, however, we need to create an instance of a generic type.  This works for internal types like `System.Int32`:

```
<cfobject name="list" type=".net" action="CREATE"
 class="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32]]">
```

But, when using our own assembly-qualified class, like the following:

```
namespace Foo.Bar.Bam
{
    public class MyClassName
}
```

that is compiled to the assembly `Foo.Bar.dll` and used like so:

```
<cfobject name="list" type=".net" action="CREATE"
 class="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Foo.Bar.Bam.MyClassName,Foo.Bar]]">
```

it fails with an "BlueDragon Internal Server Error" with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Foo.Bar]]' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.AppDomain.Load(String assemblyString)
   at com.nary.util.ClassUtils.forName(String className)
   at com.naryx.tagfusion.cfm.tag.cfOBJECT.render(cfSession session)
   at com.naryx.tagfusion.cfm.tag.cfTag.coreRender(cfSession _Session)
   at com.naryx.tagfusion.cfm.engine.cfSession.onRequest(cfFile requestFile)
   at com.naryx.tagfusion.cfm.engine.cfEngine.service(cfSession _Session)
```

Without the assembly qualification, it fails with a CFML error:

```
Failed to load class, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Foo.Bar.Bam.MyClassName]]
```

Is there any way to create an instance of a generic type using ?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the name of your Assembly (dll) not the keyword `Assembly`.

Given:

```
namespace Me
{
   public class Foo { }
}
```

and compiling to MyStuff.Dll; the class would be

```
class="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Me.Foo, MyStuff]]">
```

Comment: edited question to clarify ("Assembly" was just a sample assembly name and not any reference to a keyword "Assembly" or the System.Reflection.Assembly class)